# magento2 board doesn't show up properly

Tags: apache2, magento2

Hello i am trying to configure a magento site in my localhost i have to change the url from localhost/magento2 to localhost here my apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2/

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

In my database i change the url

[image]

but my site looks like this

[image]

if a click y link i get 404 not found error for example
**http://localhost/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check if you have a .htaccess default file on pub/static location ?
If you are missing that, put one there by copying from default Magento files..
Also if check if you have enabled mod_rewrite module in apache2.

Comment: Using question marks makes your post look like it's asking questions. Can you edit this to be more like an Answer?

Comment: a2enmod rewrite

Comment: service apache2 restart